# Terminal shows “ImportError: No module named pyperclip"

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, terminal, python-3.6

I was writing a code in which the user would run a python program on the Terminal ( I am using OSX ) and the program would copy the username’s password to the clipboard.

Here’s the code:

```
import sys
import pyperclip

passwords={'AaruDon':'zxcvbnasdjl@!#@!#4324(3’,’Sandy’:’qjljeqkjleq’} # AaruDon and Sandy are usernames that the user might input in the Terminal

idd=sys.argv[1] # idd would be the username that the user will put in the terminal while he is opening the program

if str(sys.argv[1])in passwords.keys():
  pyperclip.copy(str(passwords[idd]))

  print(' The password has been copied to the clipboard')

else:
  print('Sorry. There is no such username.')
```

When I run this program I get:

> ImportError: No module named pyperclip

Believe me, I have imported pyperclip in some  older program before and it did work! I don’t know why is it throwing this error if I try to run this from the Terminal!

How do I get rid of this?

NOTE: Pyperclip is installed. I have checked it before too

EDIT 1) I ran another program in the Terminal which also used pyperclip and it did work! The problem is with this program only

Comment: @DavidG It is already installed

Comment: try `pip install pyperclip` and see what message you get, then you should check if you have different version of python installed and which one you are using running this script and if this version as access to `pyperclip`

Comment: @Dadep It is already installed

Comment: Have you checked it is in your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: Maybe you have installed it for one version of Python, but when running from the terminal you are using a different version which does not have it installed.

Comment: @DavidG I have installed it just an hour ago! If that is the case, how do I fix it!?

Comment: @Silveris , could you please educate me a bit about that?

Comment: @AaryanDewan Type `env | grep PYTHONPATH` in a terminal and see if it gives a result. If it does, try to find the `pyperclip` module in one of the path of your `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: @Silveris , it doesn’t give any result :(

Comment: @AaryanDewan Then try doing `export PYTHONPATH=/path` where `/path` is the path to the directory where `pyperclip` is installed.

Answer (score 3):

See here: https://inventwithpython.com/hacking/chapter2.html

I had the same problem. Download it and put in the same dir as your script.

https://inventwithpython.com/pyperclip.py